# what is the reason behind DC level shift of the optoisolator ouput(collector of photo transistor) terminal?

Tags: opto-isolator, optoelectronics

[image]i am using SFH-610A optoisolator to switch 1KHZ PWM signal. on input side of opto i am triggering from micro controller with series resistor 500 ohms. and on the output side i have pull-up of 3.3V which is connected to collector with 1Kohm resistor. then the collector terminal is connected to another micro pin through 1k resistor. i am seeing DC level shift of 2V on the collector terminal.can anyone explain the reason behind that ??

Comment: Can you provide a circuit diagram

Comment: i have updated the question. check that..output of R2 will go to micro controller pin.

Comment: How much is the duty cycle pwm? 60%?

Comment: it will vary from 0 to 100%..but right now i am checking at 50%

Answer (score 0):

R2 and R3 form a voltage divider on the 3.3 volt supply, so the voltage at the opto collector should be 1.65 volts.

Comment: yes if it is like that my output should toggle between 0 to 1.65 but it is toggling between 2 to 3.3V. read the question again..

Answer (score 0):

You can Imagine the optocoupler as an NPN Transistor. A ideal NPN Transistor can be seen as a switch. For the calculation you have to differ between two cases - First: switch is open so no current can run through the switch, the current runs through R1 and R2! So the voltage at the collector should be 1.65V Second: The switch is closed, the current then runs through R1 and the switch - no current over R2 so no voltage drop over R2. The voltage at the Collector is 0 (with a real transistor almost 0)

Here is a image from my calulation. [image]

The real voltage heavily depends on what transistor you are using.
I hope I got the question right.

Comment: No. my question is my output is toggling from 2V to 3V. when switch is on i am seeing 2V and when the switch is off i am seeing 3V at the collector output, instead of 0.25 to 3V. and in the circuit that i have shown the R2 resistor other end is connected to micro controller pin but not to ground.

Comment: Please update the circuit diagram to show the complete picture. Folks are trying to answer your question based upon what is shown where R2 is connected between the collector and ground.

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to the opto coupler. Can you remove the opto device and measure the voltage when R3 is shorted to ground (should be 0v) and not (should be 1.65v). Do this with a DVM. Btw are you measuring the voltage in your application with an ADC?

Comment: Also is the microcontroller pin connected to R2 configured as an input?